# How to use a struct in a sub function

Tags: c

I don't know how to use the 'kule' in a sub-function. I marked as *********!!!*** at the error in the code.

Which parameter i must write in a function ?

> void coz( struct ??????,int disk, int* kaynak, int* yardimci, int* hedef)

---

```
#define disk_sayisi 5

typedef struct Platform {
    int bar1[disk_sayisi];
    int bar2[disk_sayisi];
    int bar3[disk_sayisi];
} platform;

void kuleleri_ekrana_yaz(platform y);
void disk_no_ata(platform *y);
void disk_tasi(platform *y, int disk);

void coz(int disk, int* kaynak, int* yardimci, int* hedef) {
    if (disk > 0) {
        printf("Kaynak:\t%d -> Hedef\t%d\n", kaynak, hedef);
*****!!!******  disk_tasi(kule, disk);
*****!!!******  kuleleri_ekrana_yaz(*kule);
    }
}

int main() {
    platform *kule;
    kule = (platform*) malloc(sizeof(platform));
    disk_no_ata(kule);
    kuleleri_ekrana_yaz(*kule);
    coz(disk, kaynak, yardimci, hedef);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`kule` is local to function `main`, so you cannot use it in `coz`. If you want to use it there, do either of the following:

1. (Not recommended:) Declare `kule` outside of `main`, and make sure to assign a valid value to it before you call `coz`:

   ```
   platform *kule;  // removed from `main` to global scope

   void coz(…) { … }

   int main() {
       kule = …;
       coz(…);
       …
   }
   ```
2. (**Recommended:**) Pass it to `coz` as an argument (via an additional parameter):

   ```
   void coz(int disk, int* kaynak, int* yardimci, int* hedef, platform *kule) { … }
                                                         // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   int main() {                                          // additional parameter
       platform *kule = …;
       coz(…, kule);
       …
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your `kule` to `coz()`:

```
void coz(int disk, int* kaynak, int* yardimci, int* hedef, platform* kule) {
    if (disk > 0) {
        printf("Kaynak:\t%d -> Hedef\t%d\n", kaynak, hedef);
        disk_tasi(kule, disk);
        kuleleri_ekrana_yaz(*kule);
    }
}

int main() {
    platform *kule;
    kule = (platform*) malloc(sizeof(platform));
    disk_no_ata(kule);
    kuleleri_ekrana_yaz(*kule);
    coz(disk, kaynak, yardimci, hedef, kule);
    return 0;
}
```